# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: Проблема в работе с файлами

Tags: python, файлы, экранирование

извините за (наверное) довольно глупый вопрос, однако, я уже 2 дня пытаюсь понять в чем проблема.
Недавно начал изучать пайтон и решил написать базовую программу для работы с файлами. Но каждый раз указывая точное расположения файла через input, пайтон выдает ошибку OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:
Я смотрел решение этой проблемы, но везде говорится о проблеме с слешами, и мол надо использовать raw строки, но мне различные исправления слешей не помогли, включая метод с raw.
Еще, раз простите, если что-то не так написал и оформил: это мой первый вопрос на ресурсе.

[image: прикрепил скриншот нужного отрывка кода и командной строки]

Comment: Попробуйте `'r'+` убрать из имени файла

Comment: Да и кавычки может не нужны... а может и нужны, если бробелы в имени файла. Если не сработает без `r`, то попробуйте ещё кавычки не вводить при вводе.

Comment: Лучше всего скидывать пример кода именно кодом, плюс у вас же четко написано что не так в самой ошибке. Советую вам ещё раз просмотреть документацию по функции fopen https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp

Comment: @CrazyElf  спасибо за ответ, или комментарий... Надо будет разобраться в структуре сайта, я даже не понимаю как отметить решение, или закрыть вопрос. Проблема оказалась в кавычках, что странно, учитывая ,что в документациях об этом ничего не сказано. В любом случае - Спасибо

Comment: @новенький Да ничего, разберётесь понемногу тут. Ваш вопрос скорее всего закроют как не особо полезный для сообщества, вам наверное ничего делать уже не нужно. Но впредь старайтесь всю возможную инфу - и код и ошибки - давать в текстовом виде и только когда совсем уж без картинок нельзя - тогда картинки.

Answer (score 0):

1. Не издеваться над строкой и передавать в качестве имени файла строку без модификаций.
2. Вводить путь без кавычек.